# Which sort takes O(n) in the given condition

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am preparing for a competition and stumbled upon this question: Considering a set of n elements which is sorted except for one element that appears out of order. Which of the following takes O(n) time?

- Quick Sort
- Heap Sort
- Merge Sort
- Bubble Sort

My reasoning is as follows:

- I know Merge sort takes O(nlogn) even in best case so its not the answer.
- Quick sort too will take O(n^2) since the array is almost sorted.
- Bubble sort can be chosen but only if we modify it slightly to check whether a swap has been made in a pass or not.
- Heap sort can be chosen as if we create the min heap of a sorted array it takes O(n) time since only one guy is not in place so he takes logn.

Hence I think its Heap sort. Is this reasoning correct? I would like to know if I'm missing something.

Comment: are you asking for an exhaustive list of sorting algorithms?? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @AntonSavin No its not a homework question I was preparing for an competitive exam and came across this question.

Comment: You seem to say all the right things .. but then you draw an incorrect conclusion that is at odds with what you just said.

Comment: @Luis No I want to know out of the given options which is the best solution to the problem as I already know insertion sort is best to sort almost sorted array but other than that would like to know from the given options.

Comment: @harold: I know we can use bubble sort but, I'm skeptical about it as we have to make modification to the standard bubble sort to get a O(n) time complexity else we end up with O(n^2) on the other hand heap sort does not need any modifications and gives us O(n).

Comment: Regarding close votes: I wonder how it is unclear what OP is asking about… He asks to confirm or correct his reasoning about a competition question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the bubble sort. From my experience most resources I have used defined bubble sort with a stopping condition of not performing any swaps in an iteration (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)). In this case indeed bubble sort will indeed stop after a linear number of steps. However, I remember that I have stumbled upon descriptions that stated a constant number of iterations, which makes your case quadratic. Therefore, all I can say about this case is "probably yes"—it depends on the definition used by the judges of the competition.

You are right regarding merge sort and quick sort—the classical versions of both algorithms enforce Θ(n log n) behavior on every input.

However, your reasoning regarding heap sort seems incorrect to me. In a typical implementation of heap sort, the heap is being built in the order opposite to the desired final order. Therefore, if you decide to build a min-heap, the outcome of the algorithm will be a reversed order, which—I guess—is not the desired one. If, on the other hand, you decide to build a max-heap, heap sort will obviously spend lots of time sifting elements up and down.

Therefore, in this case I'd go with bubble sort.

Comment: But in case of heap sort don't you think sifting elements up and down will occur only when the elements are not sorted hence sifting will occur only once since only one element is out of place?

Comment: @SabirAhmed: the thing is, if you want to apply heap sort to an array [1 2 3 4], the heap you need to build is (for example) [4 3 2 1]. This is because of the way heap is later deconstructed into a sorted array: the first step in each iteration is to swap first element with the last element of the heap. For this swapping to result in a increasing order the heap must have the biggest element as the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad question because you can guess which answer is *supposed* to be right, but it takes so many assumptions to make it it *actually* right that the question is meaningless.

If you code bubblesort as shown on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), then it will stop in O(n) *if* the element that's out of order is "below" its proper place with respect to the sort iteration.   If it's above, then it moves no more than one position toward its proper location on each pass.

To get the element unconditionally to its correct location in O(n), you'd need a variation of bubblesort that alternately makes passes in each direction.

The conventional implementations of the other sorts are O(n log n) on nearly sorted input, though Quicksort can be O(n^2) if you're not careful.  A proper implementation with a [Dutch National Flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) partition is required to prevent bad behavior.

Heapsort takes only O(n) time to build the heap, but Theta(n log n) time to pull n items off the heap in sorted order, each in Theta(log n) time.